# aggregation (many value in one field) elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, request, elasticsearch-py

I have many values in one field, when I do an aggregations, I receive these values as separate values.

**Exemple :**

```
name : jess , Region : new york 
name : jess , Region : poland
```

**request :**

```
  query = {
        "size": total,
        "aggs": {
        "buckets_for_name": {
            "terms": {
                 "field": "name",
                 "size": total
             },
            "aggs": {
                "region_terms": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "region",
                        "size": total
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        }
    }
```

**with** `response["aggregations"]["buckets_for_name"]["buckets"]` **i get** :

```
 {'key': 'jess ', 'doc_count': 61, 'region_terms': {'doc_count_error_upper_bound': 0, 'sum_other_doc_count': 0, 'buckets': [{'key': 'oran', 'doc_count': 60}, {'key': 'new ', 'doc_count': 1}, {'key': 'york', 'doc_count': 1}]}}, {'key': 'jess ', 'doc_count': 50, 'egion_terms': {'doc_count_error_upper_bound': 0, 'sum_other_doc_count': 0, 'buckets': [{'key': 'poland', 'doc_count': 50}]}}
```

**with**

```
pretty_results = []
for result in response["aggregations"]["buckets_for_name"]["buckets"]:
    d = dict()
    d["name"] = result["key"]
    d["region"] = []
    for region in result["region_terms"]["buckets"]:
        d["region "].append(region ["key"])
        pretty_results.append(d)
        print(d)
```

**i get** :

```
{'name': 'jess ', 'region ': ['new' , 'york', 'poland']}
```

**I want to get this result:**

```
{'name': 'jess ', 'region ': ['new york', 'poland']}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `region` (and I presume `name`) fields were analyzed using the standard analyzer which rendered `new york` to be split into the tokens [`new`, `york`].

What you may want to do is set up a `keyword` mapping to treat the strings as standalone tokens:

```
PUT regions
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "fielddata": true,
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "region": {
        "type": "text",
        "fielddata": true,
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After that, perform your aggs on the `.keyword` fields:

```
{
  "size": 200,
  "aggs": {
    "buckets_for_name": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name.keyword",         <---
        "size": 200
      },
      "aggs": {
        "region_terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "region.keyword",   <---
            "size": 200
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to keep `newyork` space-less, look into the [`pattern_replace`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29873779/8160318) filter within your analyzers.

---

EDIT from the comments
Aggs are not a part of the query -- they have their own scope -- so change this

```
{
  "query": {
    "aggs": {
      "buckets_for_name": {
```

to this

```
{
  "query": {
     // possibly leave the whole query attribute out
   },
   "aggs": {
      "buckets_for_name": {
   ...
```

Comment: I got a`[ ]` as a result !

Comment: i use  `PUT mytable/_mapping {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "fielddata": true,
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "region": {
        "type": "text",
        "fielddata": true,
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
}`

Comment: what does `GET mytable/_search` return? Can you paste it here?

Comment: `{ "took": 53, "timed_out": false,"_shards": {  "total": 1,"successful": 1,
      "skipped": 0,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": {
         "value": 2395,
         "relation": "eq"
      },
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "mytable",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "7769",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "id_mytable": 7769,
               "date": "2020-07-21"
               " region": "poland",
               "name": "AdminDB",
            }
         },
`

Comment: If you look closely, the `region` field name has a leading space: " region". Fix this and it'll work!

Comment: i got this error `{
   "error": {
      "root_cause": [
         {
            "type": "parsing_exception",
            "reason": "unknown query [aggs]",
            "line": 3,
            "col": 11
         }
      ],
      "type": "parsing_exception",
      "reason": "unknown query [aggs]",
      "line": 3,
      "col": 11,
      "caused_by": {
         "type": "named_object_not_found_exception",
         "reason": "[3:11] unknown field [aggs]"
      }
   },
   "status": 400
}`

Comment: my query : `GET /mytable/_search  
{   
"query" : {
  "aggs": {
    "buckets_for_name": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name.keyword",         
        "size": 200
      },
      "aggs": {
        "region_terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "region.keyword",   
            "size": 200
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
}`

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: I got `{
   "error": {
      "root_cause": [
         {
            "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason": "query malformed, empty clause found at [3:4]"
         }
      ],
      "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason": "query malformed, empty clause found at [3:4]"
   },
   "status": 400
}`

Comment: Aggs should be *outside* of the `query` statement. And it must not be empty either... Post your full query w/ the aggs & query and I'll fix it for ya.

Comment: `GET /mytable/_search  
{
        "size": 222,
        "aggs": {
        "buckets_for_name": {
            "terms": {
                 "field": "name.keyword",
                 "size": 2222
             },
            "aggs": {
                "region_terms": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "region.keyword",
                        "size": 222
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        }
    }`

Comment: with python code: ` total = mytableDocument.search().count()       query = { "size": total, "aggs": { "buckets_for_name": {  "terms": {"field": "name.keyword","size": total
 },
            "aggs": {
                "egion_terms": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "region.keyword",
                        "size": total
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        }
    }

    es = Elasticsearch()
    response = es.search(index= "mytable",body=query,size=total) `

Comment: `response["aggregations"]["buckets_for_name"]["buckets"]` didn't return anything, that's my problem

Comment: Investigate `response`, then `response["aggregations"]` and go from there....